# How to import multi-value fields into profile2 using the Migrate module

Tags: 7, users, migrations, importing-exporting

I have users each with a profile using the profile2 module. I am using a [cookbook](http://drupal.org/node/1285276) based on the Migrate [framework](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) to create the users and import profile data.

Sample CSV data would be:

```
"member_nr","email","username","tel_1"
"1001","new.tester@example.com","new tester","00000 12345-213"
```

But one of the profile fields is a text list using the checkboxes / radio buttons widget. According to the GUI, the values are stored in the format key|label.

So the field has values:

```
soccer|soccer
weight lifting|weight lifting
boxing|boxing
tennis|tennis
cooking|cooking
```

So I am trying to import data similar to:

```
"member_nr","email","username","tel_1", "interests"
"1001","new.tester@example.com","new tester","00000 12345-213", "soccer, weight lifting, boxing, tennis, cooking"
```

However, when running the import, I get an error that says:

> SQLSTATE[22001]:String data, right truncated: 1406 data too long for column field_interests' at row 1: INSERT INTO... [the data from the CSV file]

How should multi values be formatted in the CSV file to be accepted?

Comment: I don't know, but commas don't work even when you don't get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're mapping the field using the right separator, e.g.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_interests', 'interests')
     ->separator(',');
```

Then make sure you've the right length in the source field (`$this->map`) and your Drupal field support such lengths as well.

If this does not help, increase the length of the destination field by SQL, drush or `hook_update`.